# Filter inside Filter

Tags: java, filter

I have a list of **Object A**. This Object A has a list of **Object B** as a property.
Given that, I'm trying to filter an array of type A based in a property of the object of type B (let's say its an ID).

Example:

```
listOfObjectA = listOfObjectA.stream().filter(a -> a.getListOfB().stream().filter(b -> b.getId() == 10));
```

I have removed the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to make the post "cleaner".

With that, I'm getting this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<B> to boolean`.

I also tried with findAny, but had no good results either.

Comment: "*`... a -> c.getListOfB()...`*" - This seems fishy. What is `c`? Is it correct to use `c` here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant 'a'

Comment: The "inner" filter should be `anyMatch(b -> b.getId() == 10)` if you want to retain `ObjectA` elements that contain at least one `ObjectB` with ID 10. If all `ObjectB` elements must be with ID 10, use `allMatch` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the second "filter" with "anyMatch". This would return a boolean value that will be used in the first "filter":

```
listOfObjectA = listOfObjectA.stream().filter(a -> a.getListOfB().stream().anyMatch(b -> b.getId() == 10));
```